# Multiple array definitions for single array in Azure API-management

Tags: arrays, azure, asp.net-core, swagger, azure-api-management

I created a project that returns an array. Looking at the swagger.json everything looks fine, importing this swagger.json . But when I download the API definition from the developer portal I see some objects like ...Array, ...Array-1, ...Array-2. Which I don't expect:

[image: Example Azure portal]

How can I prevent this? How can I ensure that the generation behaves the same as my normal object (so no dashes, but dots). I created an example project that reproduces my issue: https://github.com/mvdiemen/SwaggerArrayGenerationExample.

Is this related to changes in Azure API management that are described over here? : https://blog.tomkerkhove.be/2018/04/13/changes-to-azure-api-management-openapi/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APIM does not support inlined schema. Try specifying schemas for response/request via $ref only, even if it's an array of object you've already defined - define a new object of type array and reference it.

So, instead of something like this:

```
"200": {
    "description": "Success",
    "schema": {
        "uniqueItems": false,
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/SwaggerGenerationSample.Models.Response.Employee"
        }
    }
}
```

Have array itself defined in definitions and reference it:

```
"200": {
    "description": "Success",
    "schema": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/EmployeeArray"
    }
}
...
"definitions": {
    "EmployeeArray": {
        "uniqueItems": false,
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/SwaggerGenerationSample.Models.Response.Employee"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Currently our schema looks like this: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mvdiemen/f34735ea197f76510d077b7a6b2a6e92/raw/02255a4c216da2d12f4e822678de19f7cc34107b/swagger.json. Is that what you refer to? Do you have an example?

Comment: Updated response

Comment: Thanks import this in APIM make it work. We are generating our swagger.json from our model in asp.net core with SwashBuckle. How can I force this in combination with SwashBuckle?

Comment: I'm not really sure, unfortunately.